# how to find the shortest path to pick several objects?

Tags: python

I want to find the best path a robot can take to pick some objects from a specific space, I ask the user for the name of things he want to pick, when he types 2, the problem is already solved, but when he types more, for example, when he types 3, my program gives him the shortest path between each two, then adds the path to a list, the robot picks the objects with same order, and that's not what I want, I want it to find the shortest way to pick all of them

```
from collections import deque, namedtuple


# we'll use infinity as a default distance to nodes.
inf = float('inf')
Edge = namedtuple('Edge', 'start, end, cost')


def make_edge(start, end, cost=1):
  return Edge(start, end, cost)


class Graph:
    def __init__(self, edges):
        # let's check that the data is right
        wrong_edges = [i for i in edges if len(i) not in [2, 3]]
        if wrong_edges:
            raise ValueError('Wrong edges data: {}'.format(wrong_edges))

        self.edges = [make_edge(*edge) for edge in edges]

    @property
    def vertices(self):
        return set(
            sum(
                ([edge.start, edge.end] for edge in self.edges), []
            )
        )

    def get_node_pairs(self, n1, n2, both_ends=True):
        if both_ends:
            node_pairs = [[n1, n2], [n2, n1]]
        else:
            node_pairs = [[n1, n2]]
        return node_pairs

    def remove_edge(self, n1, n2, both_ends=True):
        node_pairs = self.get_node_pairs(n1, n2, both_ends)
        edges = self.edges[:]
        for edge in edges:
            if [edge.start, edge.end] in node_pairs:
                self.edges.remove(edge)

    def add_edge(self, n1, n2, cost=1, both_ends=True):
        node_pairs = self.get_node_pairs(n1, n2, both_ends)
        for edge in self.edges:
            if [edge.start, edge.end] in node_pairs:
                return ValueError('Edge {} {} already exists'.format(n1, n2))

        self.edges.append(Edge(start=n1, end=n2, cost=cost))
        if both_ends:
            self.edges.append(Edge(start=n2, end=n1, cost=cost))

    @property
    def neighbours(self):
        neighbours = {vertex: set() for vertex in self.vertices}
        for edge in self.edges:
            neighbours[edge.start].add((edge.end, edge.cost))

        return neighbours

    def dijkstra(self, source, dest):
        assert source in self.vertices, 'Such source node doesn\'t exist'
        distances = {vertex: inf for vertex in self.vertices}
        previous_vertices = {
            vertex: None for vertex in self.vertices
        }
        distances[source] = 0
        vertices = self.vertices.copy()

        while vertices:
            current_vertex = min(
                vertices, key=lambda vertex: distances[vertex])
            vertices.remove(current_vertex)
            if distances[current_vertex] == inf:
                break
            for neighbour, cost in self.neighbours[current_vertex]:
                alternative_route = distances[current_vertex] + cost
                if alternative_route < distances[neighbour]:
                    distances[neighbour] = alternative_route
                    previous_vertices[neighbour] = current_vertex

        path, current_vertex = deque(), dest
        while previous_vertices[current_vertex] is not None:
            path.appendleft(current_vertex)
            current_vertex = previous_vertices[current_vertex]
        if path:
            path.appendleft(current_vertex)
        return path

thing = [
    ["a0", "b0", 2], ["a0", "a1", 1],
    ["a1", "a2", 1], ["a2", "a3", 1],
    ["a3", "a4", 1], ["a4", "b4", 2],

    ["b0", "c0", 2], ["b0", "b1", 1],
    ["b1", "b2", 1], ["b2", "b3", 1],
    ["b3", "b4", 1], ["b4", "c4", 2],

    ["c0", "c1", 1], ["c1", "c2", 1],
    ["c2", "c3", 1], ["c3", "c4", 1],


    ["a4", "b4", 2], ["a4", "a5", 1],
    ["a5", "a6", 1], ["a6", "a7", 1],
    ["a7", "a8", 1], ["a8", "b8", 2],

    ["b4", "c4", 2], ["b4", "b5", 1],
    ["b5", "b6", 1], ["b6", "b7", 1],
    ["b7", "b8", 1], ["b8", "c8", 2],

    ["c4", "c5", 1], ["c5", "c6", 1],
    ["c6", "c7", 1], ["c7", "c8", 1]
]
other=[]

for i in thing:
    a=[]
    a.append(i[1])
    a.append(i[0])
    a.append(i[2])
    other.append(a)

result = thing + other


graph = Graph(result)

NumberOfThings = int(input('how many things would you like to pick ? '))

ThingsToPick=[]

for i in range(0, NumberOfThings):
    name=input(' - ')
    ThingsToPick.append(name)

len=len(ThingsToPick)

way=[]

for i in range(0,len-1):
    for j in list(graph.dijkstra(ThingsToPick[i], ThingsToPick[i+1])):
        way.append(j)

print(way)
```

Comment: Sounds like classical [travelling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem). Simple approach: Try all possible orders, calculate needed path length for each, return shortest.

Comment: What is your question? You know that people build careers around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with vertices amd edges in python. The below code has one function distancebetweenvertices([a,b]) you need to replace this with the real distance function.

```
import itertools

def distance(alist)
   pairs=[[l[i],l[i+1]] for i in range(0,len(l)-2)]
   d=0
   for pair in pairs:
      d += distancebetweenvertices(pair)
   return d

l=['a','b','c','d']
ways=itertools.combinations(l)
bestdistance=distance(l)
bestway=l
for way in ways:
   if distance(way) < bestdistance:
      bestway=way
```

At first, we define a function for the total distance between vertices in a list. The distance function separates the list into pairs, calculates the distance between each two using the (placeholder) distancebetweenvertices function and sums it up.

Then it creates a list of all possible ways via itertools, sets the start values for bestway and bestdistance to the order the user gave the input and the according distance. Now it checks for every possible way if the total distance is smaller. If yes, it replaces bestway and bestdistance with this way and this distance. In the end, you will have best way and according distance in the bestway and bestdistance variables.

Hope that helps.